# When is it okay to edit posts for "Code Formatting?"

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, edits, code-formatting

I recently posted this answer:

- [Continuing the most outer loop from the most nested one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24620229/355682)

It contains a block of Java code, written by me, currently under [an edit war](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/24620229/revisions) between myself and the original asker of the question.

Under "discussion", is not the content of the code, but the **formatting**.

I am very much for readable code, and so when the OP edited my answer to insert Egyptian Brackets into my answer, I reverted it. (Just as I would revert an edit that went through and changed all instances of "Color" or "Humor" to "Colour" and "Humour")

This went back and forth for a while, before I explicitly asked the OP to stop editing my answer. He did... but then suggested edits for the exact same changes started showing up — and that's the reason we're here: the community itself seems conflicted as to whether changing the format is a valid edit.

Not sure what the requirements are to view these, but:

1. [Suggested Edit 1 -- Approved](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5258354),
2. [Suggested Edit 2 -- Rejected](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5258217),
3. [Suggested Edit 3 -- Approved](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5258075),
4. [Suggested Edit 4 -- Rejected by Author](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5258488).

And then to top everything off, another well-meaning community member edited the edit, because they thought the altered code was unclear, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/24620229/21).

So, Stack Exchange, when *should* code formatting edits be allowed, and when should they be rolled back?

(And in this specific case, can we maybe get a lock on the post? I'm still getting suggested edits from "community" every 30 minutes or so)

Comment: I hate it when people think their style of formatting is better than mine and just edit **my** post. IMO only edit a post if the code is not formatted at all or obviously wrong.

Comment: See [When is it appropriate to edit someone else's code?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101583/when-is-it-appropriate-to-edit-someone-elses-code)

Comment: Clearly what your code-edit-foe is doing is inappropriate - making the same changes over and over again rather than posting a comment or just moving on could even be counted as abusive!

Comment: Imo, placing the brackets on a empty line is just a waste of space, especially on SO. However, if that's the only thing that's "wrong" with an answer or question, there is __no__ reason to edit the post. __Formatting edits are only valid when the post had no / barely any formatting to begin with.__

Comment: That said, bickering about style is a waste of time. The editor shouldn't have bothered to edit, but I don't really see a reason to revert it either.

Comment: The same user made a drastic edit to [another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/24654285/revisions) that was subsequently rolled back by a mod. Perhaps they need to be educated about what types of edits are appropriate.

Comment: I, too, am very much for readable code, and so if someone would have edited an answer of mine to *remove* K&R bracketing style in favor of a dramatic increase of whitespace I too would have reverted it... :)

Comment: Separately, you really ought to use the languages conventions in answers and Java is definitely for Egyptian brackets.

Comment: Note that the anonymous user making the edit suggestions is probably the same person (as the comment used is often copy/pasted from the last one).  And that the first edit by an anonymous user was right after Jagger was asked by a moderator to stop editing the question, and was a duplicate of Jagger's previous edit.  There is strong circumstantial evidence that Jagger is "not editing" after the moderator asked them to stop by editing anonymously.  "Community" consists of anything an anonymous reviewer suggests that the horde of robo-reviewers approve.

Comment: In the future, just flag for moderator attention instead of engaging in an edit war. I flagged because of the repeated anonymous *minor* suggested edits and a mod has already locked the post.

Comment: @Yakk - Those reviewers won't be doing so again for a couple of days.

Comment: "I'm your Egyptian (Bracket) Lover, baby ..."

Comment: @Eternal21: One thing I've not seen discussed with the bracing style is whether a single statement controlled by an `if` requires a brace block.  IMHO, a major advantage of Allman style is that an `if` that controls a single non-compound statement looks very different from one that controls a compound statement, thus minimizing the risk of confusion.

Comment: @Brad: If you asked me, a couple of days is too modest. Should be a month minimum. It's because of reviewers like that, that I stopped reviewing any content on the site. My time is wasted trying to do an honest review only to be overthrown by those who don't _really_ care.

Comment: A lot of different people use different formatting methods, CSS is a good example of this, for things like leaving spaces between : and description (if that makes sense) or having the } on a separate line.  There is not really a correct method, but people often edit one way or the other.

Comment: What I want to know is if the anonymous suggestions all came from the same IP address, and if that's the same as the OP of the question.

Comment: The edit changes more than just the formatting and should have been rejected for that reason alone.  Note the difference in how the `earlyBreak` variable is set:  `earlyBreak = true;` vs `if (earlyBreak = i == 3) {`

Comment: @Eternal21 I guess most people do not even know these days what K&R stands for and what kind of book every (not only C-) programmer should have read.

Comment: @Jagger I guess some people are still stuck in the 80s, working on 80x24 character monitors, which forces them to pick brevity (K&R) over readability (Allman).  Certainly not the case in my shop.

Comment: @Eternal21 I can see that there are still some programmers that are paid by the line of code. Allman more readable? In what way?

Comment: @Jagger Just accept the fact you are in a minority, and move on: http://www.terminally-incoherent.com/blog/2009/04/10/the-only-correct-indent-style/

Comment: @ArtB A valid point. That's probably why I prefer Allman, actually; my background is in C#, and C# convention is for Allman (see: [any MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg509017.aspx) reference page)

Comment: @Eternal21 Ah, the argumentum ad populum. One survey from 5 years ago that agrees with the post author is nowhere close to eliminating sample bias. How is it more readable again? Is it because you have to read more of it? Most of the time, brevity IS readability. The opposite argument (verbosity) is much less convincing.

Comment: @Eternal21 Just to end the discussion. How does being in minority make one not be right? If the majority votes that 2+2 is 5, are they right? But maybe it is according to this modern democracy we have nowadays in some countries that used to be republic...If you have your theory then give some measures that can back it up. K&R - less lines of code, that is a measure.

Answer (score 123, accepted):

You should not be making edits that make changes that are a matter of personal preference; the changes should be clearly and objectively better.  In terms of code, you shouldn't be changing code from one perfectly acceptable style of formatting to another, based on your personal preferences.

Additionally, as with any edit conflict, you should not participate in an edit war.  If someone reverts an edit that you feel is appropriate you should immediately stop editing the post and flag for moderator attention instead of feeding the edit war.  Generally, if it is deemed that the matter is indeed an issue of personal preference, the author of the post is the one whose content should remain, however, if even the author of a post shouldn't be reverting an edit that objectively improves the post in a way that is not an issue of personal preference.  Rolling back appropriate, significant, and helpful edits that still maintain the author's actual content is effectively vandalizing your own post and is not acceptable.  (Once again though, it's the moderator that will resolve such an issue, even if you feel this is the case you shouldn't continue to apply the edit.)

Comment: Is there a precedent for continuously rejecting suggested edits that suggest the same thing? (Via the author's instant-5-vote power)

Comment: I think it makes more sense to just downvote and post a better-formatted answer in cases where the OP doesn't like changes and rejects, rather than edit war and/or moderator flagging.  It's too hard to separate 'personal preference' from not, particularly on a site like this.  The OP is the owner of their post, if they don't like your improvements move on and post your own.

Comment: The Stack Overflow answer in question was written by the asker of the question here, so he is doing the reverting, not the editing.

Comment: @RavenDreamer As I've said, you shouldn't be getting into an edit war with another user.  You should be flagging for moderator attention after the first time they (try to) re-apply the same change, rather than letting it continue back and forth for dozens of revisions.

Comment: @Servy Right. So should I or should I not be rejecting suggested edits?

Comment: @RavenDreamer If an edit is improper you can reject it.  All of the edits suggested to your post really should have been rejected by reviewers if you didn't, as [is indicated here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/263115/when-is-it-okay-to-edit-answers-for-code-formatting/263121?noredirect=1#comment56235_263115)

Answer (score 63):

It's OK when the readability is improved. It is not OK when the edit is essentially about stylistic preferences.

Examples where it is OK to edit:

- Unneeded and incorrect indentation

  ```
          void Foo() {
              doSomething();
              if (bar) {
                   doSomethingElse();
          }
          }
  ```
- Too much code on one line (often an issue in HTML and JS code blocks in my experience)

  ```
  void Foo(string one, string two, string three, string four, string five, string six, string seven, string eight, string nine)
  {
      doSomething();
  }
  ```

Examples where it is not OK to edit, and where you may rollback the edit:

- Brace style

  ```
  void Foo()
  {
      doSomething();
  }
  ```
- Syntax preference

  ```
  if (foo) { …code… } else if (bar == true) { …code… }
  ```

I think you get what I mean with these examples.

Comment: Must...fight...urge...to...edit...

Comment: What are you trying to highlight in the last example?  Because I bet that many people would agree that regardless of brace style, `if ( !foo && bar ) { }` is better, and for more than just "style".

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor I was trying to show `if (foo)` vs `if (foo == true)`, perhaps not a good example.

Comment: @Stijn Yeah, I think that that's beyond style, and into the realm of things that could justifiably be edited/fixed.

Comment: I think all of these are reasonable, but I think that in every case the OP is always free to rollback, and then further edits of that nature should stop.  (Of course, if the OP reverts to a very badly formatted answer, it should be downvoted.)

Comment: @Joe No, it is *not* okay to be making changes that are purely stylistic and a matter of your personal preference, with the expectation that the OP would roll it back if their preferences don't align.  *Such edits are inappropriate edits*.  Likewise, if a post author is reverting edits that are obvious and significant edits to a post *that is vandalizing content and is equally unacceptable*.  You should flag for moderator attention because users are not allowed to vandalize their own posts.  They don't have the right to damage even their own content once they've posted it.

Comment: @Servy Sorry, by 'all' I meant that I agreed with Stijn (that the top ones were fine, not the bottom ones).  Bad wording there.  However, I disagree about the post author's reverting rights.

Comment: @Joe That is the site policy.  Whether you agree with it or not, it is true.  By posting content to SE you are giving up a number of rights to that content, among those rights is the ability to vandalize it.  That is inappropriate behavior that is a violation of the rules, and you will be stopped from doing so if reported.

Comment: @Servy, no, you don't really have the right to vandalize someone else's work without restraint. See [section 4d](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/legalcode): "*You must not distort, mutilate, modify or take other derogatory action in relation to the Work which would be prejudicial to the Original Author's honor or reputation*".

Comment: @Bruno I didn't say that you can vandalize their content.  I said that they don't have the right to vandalize their own contributions.  If someone is attempting to vandalize their own content, they can and generally will be stopped from doing so.

Comment: @Servy, sorry, I misread.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor Your suggestion cannot possibly be better, because it has spaces on the inside of its parentheses.  (HHOS)

Comment: Brace style in many languages is not a matter of preference, there is often a single, and objectively correct way of doing it.

Comment: Except unnecessary curly brace, what's wrong with first example's indentation? I prefer such style to `if (bar) doSomething();` one liners, especially when `else/if else` statements follow, which makes one liners even less readable.

Comment: @doc Both closing braces are indented equally, the first closing brace should be indented more.

Comment: I usually add/fix indentation (to improve legibility), while trying my best to respect the original poster's style preference regarding newlines, braces, etc.

Answer (score 9):

I would encourage code style improvements in answers if they stick to "official" (or "by consensus") standards. Specially Java has had for very long time the Sun's [Code Conventions for the Java <sup>TM</sup> Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html) publicly available<sup>1</sup>.

On the other hand, it should suffice one edit proposal rejection to refrain anyone from further editing your code.

But you have to understand that, as it stands, your code style doesn't conform to the by-consensus Java coding standards and that many experienced Java developers will still feel the impulse to change it. If you want to avoid such edits, you should state it explicitly in your post.

Personally, if I'd find your post useful, I'd first up-vote it and afterwards comment on the style. But I wouldn't take offence if anyone would edit some code I write in a language I'm not used to, just to make it more conform to existing conventions. That would help me as well to improve my coding practices.

---

Notes:

<sup>1</sup> I have to thank you for your question here, as trying to answer it I have realized that Oracle doesn't support the above mentioned conventions any more (I don't know since when), making my point somehow weaker.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about it no longer being maintained, it's not really the kind of document that needs to be maintained. It's last revision was in 1999, it didn't have the "no maintained" disclaimer [in Feb 2014](http://web.archive.org/web/20140213083335/http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html). There have been minor changes to the Java syntax between 1999 (e.g. generics), but nothing dramatic that would invalidate this document.

Comment: The main problem I have with it is that it uses 1/2 tab as a unit of indentation, yet it allows to mix spaces and tabs for this, which can be very messy if your editor doesn't replace tabs with spaces automatically (but then it's more natural for 1 tab to be 1 level of indentation): "*Four spaces should be used as the unit of indentation. The exact construction of the indentation (spaces vs. tabs) is unspecified. Tabs must be set exactly every 8 spaces (not 4).*". The other problem is that neither Netbeans nor Eclipse follow these guidelines by default (but you can configure this), I think.

Comment: @Bruno I must admit that it is a long time without reading Sun's conventions. I use the IDE tools for styling. I agree that those conventions are neither complete nor perfect, but fortunately the parenthesis style is consistent across both NetBeans and Eclipse. And its visual impact is too strong to expect experienced **Java** programmers not to restyle it. (Notice that I stress _Java_, as I believe this doesn't hold true in many other programming languages.)

Answer (score -3):

It is okay to edit for formatting when one believes the edit is an improvement that does not change the meaning of the post.  Since the original poster always has editing privileges, the original poster gets to decide whether a formatting edit is an improvement, and whether an edit changes the meaning of the post.  In this case, you, the original poster, made it clear that you didn't consider the edit an improvement by reverting it, and the editor should have stopped after the first time that happened.

Comment: I improved your formatting. I guess that's ok. ;D

Comment: @Theolodis I know you're just trying to prove a point, but splitting words in the middle is *not* a formatting change. It is also *definitively* not an improvement. While code indentation styles are contentious, nobody can say your edit is easier to read than the original, so your implied analogy doesn't hold.

Comment: @Theolodis It is not. You are misusing your editing privileges.

Comment: The people editing this answer should know very well they are not proper edits, and they should stop. If they wish to make a point, they can do so with an answer or comment.

Comment: @Theolodis also, if you where to edit code like this, and just cut a tag down the middle, what are the odds that it would still work?

Answer (score -8):

As for bracketing, some languages make the style non-optional in their style guide. So it depends on the language. In general, all languages will have some restrictions on style and formatting. This can be either via documentation, or via SonaType/IDE configuration files.

If we do not follow such style guides and consider style/formatting as purely "personal preference" then by definition *any style no matter how ridiculous* is valid provided it is that author's personal preference.

For example, suppose some deranged author wishes to use 100s of spaces before every curly brace and no white space in the method body, for example,

```
def someMethod()                                                                                              {
statement1;statement2;statement3;etc
                                                                                                                                       }
```

We cannot allow this, and it is style guides that give us a formal means to do so.

Comment: What is meant by "non-optional" in a "style guide"?  If the designer of a language wishes to require things to be formatted a particular way, that should be part of the language specification.  Otherwise, if authors feel that in some particular situation code is more readable if written differently, then those who agree with their judgment should regard such formatting as making the code better, while those who disagree should regard it as having made the code worse.  Especially with regard to code snippets whose purpose is to provide a "skeleton" for the real meat of a question or answer...

Comment: ...I favor a style which would be absurdly brief in any sort of production code. For example, I'll often put a class or method definition on a single line if it will fit without wrapping, or on two lines with the open brace starting the second line.  While I don't consider vertical space overly "precious" here, having the text which explains the purpose of a piece of code (which goes above the code) fit on the screen with the text which explains detailed aspects of it (which goes below) is often nicer than having excessive separation between them.

Comment: Otherwise, I would say that the proper purpose of edits is to make a post say what the editor believes the author either intended to say, or would want the post to say.  If someone would expect the author of a post would disagree with a proposed change, that would suggest that the prospective editor should write his own post wherein he might say something like "If you only need to X when Y, then A's solution Z will work.  It's important to realize, however, that when Y does not hold, then it will be necessary to either use approach Z' if Y' holds, or else restructure the problem."