# Is Community auto modifying code indentations now?

Tags: discussion, community-user

Looking at the [edit history for this question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/13372194/revisions) we see community put in a edit

> improving the readability of the source code by reducing the indentation from 8 to 4 and reducing the numer of lines

Which was then changed by svic

> open brace on new line is more common in C#

Which was changed back again by community 10 minutes later

> improving the readability of the source code by reducing the indentation from 8 to 4 and reducing the numer of lines

Is this a new automation feature of `Community` to go and change peoples code? and why did it basically go and "roll back" svic's change?

Comment: Looks like an edit war. Interesting thing is that this user was in another edit war related meta discussion a few days ago.

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion How much do you want to bet that it's the same guy proposing those anonymous edits? :P

Comment: Being the exact same edit text verbatim, I am confidant it is.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I was more thinking the same guy discussed in the other Meta question, since the edits started a bit after that the Meta discussion came up, but yeah, it's almost the same person proposing the same edit for this particular question.

Comment: $0, I know it's the same guy @user3580294. He seems extremely committed to the greater good of "editing and improving" all posts ;-P

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Community is listed as the editor whenever an anonymous person (i.e. someone who isn't logged in) proposes an edit and is approved.

In any case, those edits shouldn't be happening, as discussed in [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/263115/when-is-it-okay-to-edit-answers-for-code-formatting) Meta question. I just rolled the question back, but I doubt that the question will be left alone. Somewhat surprised that the edits continued despite *two* mods rolling them back, and that the OP is the same as the one in the Meta question. Interesting indeed...

Comment: Thanks, I did not know anonymous edits where recorded that way. I thought it was part of the automated script.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain No problem! Glad I could help.

Comment: A similar thing happens when reviewers "improve" Suggested Edits. Community's action depends on whether the reviewer unticks the "Original edit was helpful" checkbox.

Comment: @indivisible In that case wouldn't the reviewer's name be listed as the edit author?

Comment: @user3580294, yes but sandwiched between is a rollback to the version previous to the suggestion and then the reviewer's edit follows. 90% sure... Or perhaps that's the flow for it an editing reviewer ignores the "1 edit has been made" warning and pushes theirs through regardless. Meh.

Comment: @indivisible Wait, if the edit was just suggested and still under review then the edit wasn't applied and so there wouldn't be something to roll back? I'm confused...

Comment: Yeah, I think you're right. I was thinking of when a reviewer who is improving a suggested edit ignores the warning that "1 edit has been made" usually indicating the suggested edit was accepted while they were working and they push their own edit through while also unticking the "edit was helpful" box. Happens more one might think.

Comment: @indivisible Ah, I see. That makes sense. Haven't seen it happen myself, probably because I don't edit all that much...

Comment: @user3580294, I spend a bit of time in the Suggested Edit review queue so I see and trigger it fairly often. Those robo-reviewers never give you enough time to fix the poor attempts at fixes...

Comment: If they shouldn't be happening, why aren't they banned in the first place?

Comment: @DanielDaranas The edits were suggested by an anonymous user, which makes bans a little difficult to use.

Answer (score 18):

[This is a targeted attempt at trolling a particular user.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/263115/when-is-it-okay-to-edit-answers-for-code-formatting) We've suspended the primary account of the person responsible, and now they appear to have taken to abusing anonymous edits to continue to troll this user. Unfortunately, reviewers keep approving these unnecessary code formatting edits.

Let me make this very clear to any reviewers reading this: do not approve edits from anonymous editors that change code formatting. If you do so, and I catch you at it, I will ban you from review. I have banned every single approver of one of these edits and will continue to do so until we find a better way to combat this troll.

If you see these edits getting through, flag them for us to look into. The community team is working on this.

Comment: ".. do not approve edits from anonymous editors that change code formatting. If you do so .." Okay, got it. Is this going to be an official SO reviewers' instruction?

Comment: Are these perma-bans? I really think that more bans need to be passed out to robo-reviewer types. I'd rather see a slightly longer queue than continue allowing the kind of crap that gets let through. On a side note: Why are anonymous users even allowed to edit?

Comment: @indivisible - Permanent bans from any part of the site are against the general moderation philosophy. I've applied 2-day bans for everyone I've seen, with a custom message describing exactly why these edits should not have been approved. I'm hoping that will be educational and will change their reviewing habits. I'm an optimist.

Comment: @BradLarson, You're a better man than me. With the frequent and loud objection and despair over the quality of reviewing in recent times I would probably take a harsher tact with them. Some people seem to show that they can't handle the responsibility or just do not have sufficiently good judgement to make consistently correct decisions - I don't see why they should be allowed to keep doing it. I'm just a lowly user though so they're safe, for now....

Comment: "do not approve edits from anonymous editors that change code formatting" Wouldn't this only be true if the edit was wrong or part of an edit war such as this? I don't really see a reason why a valid edit that improves the formatting of a post should be rejected just because the user is anonymous. (I mean a substantial edit, not an unnecessary one like in the example.) Is it just because of the higher probability that they are trolling someone?

Comment: "If you do so, and I catch you at it, I will ban you from review." - Wow, that's harsh.

Comment: @SteveBennett You obviously don't know about the lazy reviewer problem [so] has.

Comment: @indivisible: True, I have a few users in mind who have been automatically banned upwards of 20 times (which, for a repeated pattern of 2, 7 and 30 days, spans more than a *year* of getting banned from review if you do the math...) and still hitting bans today. They seem to be completely unfazed by these bans, and I shudder to think how much damage they might have allowed to take place on the site.

Comment: @BradLarson: Would it be worth suggesting a feature that suggested edits by anonymous users go only to the OP for approval, rejection, or improvement, instead of into the community queue?  Maybe also discoverable by high-rep users via the post "pending edits" count.  If we're worried about post-and-dump OPs, it could go into the queue after a couple weeks of inaction by the OP, but I don't think anonymous edits provide that much value.  In essence, it changes anonymous edit suggestions into a comment directed to the OP, while still preventing spam (the comments aren't widely visible).

Comment: Trolls will then sit on the river and wait for the banned from review to pass by.