# User making a lot of unnecessary revisions

Tags: support, edits

I noticed that an established user (18k+ rep) has been making a lot of unnecessary revisions when they recently edited one of my answers.  Some of the changes appear to be incorrect, but most are just minor, often a matter of personal preference.  For example:

- Replacing tabs with spaces,
- Changing spacing to match own style (when it's already consistent),
- Replacing contractions with full forms (`don't` -> `do not`),
- Removing double spaces (I double-space between sentences -- a lot of people do),
- Incorrectly marking syntax types where no syntax highlighting exists for the actual language (for example, marking PowerShell with `<!-- language: sh -->`).

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/17758298/2) an example.

I'm not really sure what to do.  I can't "decline" the revisions because they have 18k rep; I can only roll them back.  Many of the revisions are to their own answers, so it'd be a bit of a pain finding the applicable edits.

Comment: Because they're now in the revision history you can ping them with @ and ask them to stop, but you might be better off raising a custom moderator flag on one of the edited posts and explaining what's happening.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/263115/355682

Comment: spaces work better in SO code samples than tabs, so that one should be a legitimate improvement. and there is a good argument you are technically incorrect to use two spaces between sentences although  it is common practice; but since there's no visible difference it's a silly thing to correct.

Comment: Using a replacement syntax highlighting is not so bad, I use C# syntax highlighting for Vala questions since both languages are quite similar.

Comment: Don't use tabs in code. Don't use tabs in code. Don't use tabs in  code.  For a very simple reason: code blocks in SO *start with 4 spaces*, so there is a chance that the indentation is going to be messed up (seen this lots and lots and lots of times).

Comment: There's nothing wrong with tabs in code samples, it's just a problem when there's a mix of tabs and spaces.  Some of the minor edits (replacing contractions, getting rid of double spaces after periods) might be so they can hit the minimum character requirement for an edit.

Comment: I am so sick of people maligning tabs. They work ***fine***.

Comment: I didn't come here to ask for your opinions on coding styles.  We all know every developer thinks their style is the one and only true way.  You code your way and I'll code mine.  Tabs work fine on SO--I've been using them for years.  At the time I learned to type, reliable sources were recommending double spaces.  (Like you said, it makes no difference.  It's just an old habit.)

Comment: @Boann See Bakuriu's comment before yours.  StackOverflow markdown relies on spaces to mark code blocks, and _mixing_ spaces and tabs is just asking for trouble.  On their own, tabs are okay, though.

Comment: @Izkata Markdown also lets you use tabs to mark code blocks.

Comment: Hm, even instances of "Don't" _in code_ are being replaced. I wonder if the editor is running a script?

Comment: @Boann Tabs in Java are rather problematic if you also try to follow the Java Coding Conventions, which say "*Four spaces should be used as the unit of indentation. The exact construction of the indentation (spaces vs. tabs) is unspecified. Tabs must be set exactly every 8 spaces (not 4)*". It's quite difficult to have 1/2 tab as an indentation level...

Comment: Enough!  No more discussion of spacing etiquette.  The point is it was unnecessary.  As far as Stack Overflow is concerned, as long as it's consistent, it doesn't matter.

Comment: "Replacing tabs with spaces..." - spaces are site policy, not tabs. You should have been doing that yourself. See [Filter Questions and Answers for tab character?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261493/filter-questions-and-answers-for-tab-character).

Comment: @halfer Maybe? He's doing some odd things with line breaks (switch to side-by-side markdown view): [(1)](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/19735567/revisions), [(2)](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/7272390/revisions), [(3)](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/16175967/revisions), [(4)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/256158/revisions), [(5)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/253048/revisions)

Comment: @Bakuriu: As of recently, we have `tab-size: 4` on the textareas, so there’s no consistency problem between how they’re displayed when editing and how Markdown renders them.

Comment: [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/24931448/revisions) another one, which the (19K) poster has recently rolled back. It contained substantial code-edits as far as I can see.

Comment: I wasn't sure if the user being referred to has been notified of the discussion, so I have done that now.

Comment: Is the issue that you do not have control over what is visible, the policy on how revisions should be done, or is it on the quality of the revision? 

Its a public discussion if it is on the control of information issue. If the issue is "meh I dont like the edits" then it should be between two people.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The correct answer to any question of the type: "A user is doing something bad that doesn't fit into a standard reporting category, what should I do?" is to raise a custom flag and write up a detailed explanation of what they did wrong.

If their bad behavior was on something that can't be flagged directly, find something of theirs that can be flagged and start your explanation with something like:  "I raised a flag here because I couldn't where the problem occurred..."

Fixing these problems is the moderators job; but because they're busy you need to explain the issue reasonably well because they don't have time go on a fishing expedition if you raise a flag and only put "Did something bad" for an explanation when it's not obvious from only looking at what was flagged.

Comment: Hmm...it's too bad you have to go find a post or comment, and you can't flag the user itself...

Comment: @PaulDraper If you could flag a user with a message like "This user is constantly messing up my posts", the mods would still have to go find those edits themselves, which is a tough job. It makes more sense to flag a post or comment. After all, that is where the problem is. You (should) have an issue with the modification, not with the user per se. If you flag a post or comment the mods will judge whether the claim is just, and they can then easily find out which user was responsible and take appropriate action.

Comment: The appropriate place to flag it if a user is "messing up my posts" is on one of the posts they messed up. Identify the user by name or number.

Comment: Before doing this, why not `@` notify the user? If they've edited a post, @UserName will notify them just as if they had commented.

Answer (score 7):

Bit of a mixed bag really, some good some bad.

The things I'd disagree with are:

- editing out contractions, that's bulking out with extra words you don't need. I see this a lot and don't understand why fluent English readers and writers do this. It's perfectly correct English and grammatical style, even for technical writing.
- tinkering with paragraph breaks - unless there's a real mess or there's a wall of text.
- fiddling with the OP's coding style, unless of course it's worthwhile breaking down a line of code that causes horizontal scrolling, or, where the code is a hellish blob with no spaces and some re-formatting would make the code more digestible and attractive to the eye.

The others can be useful:

- Replacing tabs with spaces is generally a good thing, the markdown HTML renderer can produce some funky formatting when tabs are present, especially when tabs and spaces are mixed.
- The `<!-- language: sh -->` hint can be useful for PowerShell to force syntax highlighting (although I've also found the `<!-- language: python-->` hint effective as well).

Comment: I remember a couple times doing the first one (expand contractions) because the actual fix to the post was below the 6-character limit.  So there is a reason, even if it's not a very good one

Comment: @Izkata: In that case, better add an invisible HTML-comment: `<!-- -->` (That's also good for separating code/comment-blocks without intervening text)

Comment: @Deduplicator you can also use `<!-->` in those cases.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, I made an edit to one of OP’s answers. He says unnecessary revisions, but
to me code highlighting **is** necessary. If someone does not like my revisions,
the `rollback` button is available. I am not going to get in a edit war over
highlighting, so if it gets rolled back, oh well. As you can see to date I have
made over [2,000 revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1002260?tab=activity&sort=revisions) so this is not some new thing I have started
doing.

Update

I have received a message from the moderators, so as a reference for everyone
here are some inappropriate edits

- replace tabs with spaces
- replacing contractions
- changing the formatting of code

Comment: +1 for the highlighting of a similar enough language. The original post had a lot of code, and code highlighting in this instance made it that much more pleasant to read in my opinion (even if it wasn't powershell specific, it did its job). http://stackoverflow.com/posts/17758298/revisions