# Could someone edit too many posts too often?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

I have yet to find an answer to this issue with searching throughout a good bit of StackExchange, so here is my issue...

I am going through as many posts as possible to fix small grammar errors, capitalize letters, add the code blocks as needed, and whatever else to make the questions a little more organized and professional. This is a good thing in my eyes, without a doubt.

My issue is that I feel like I am making too many edits to posts too fast. In an hour, I can most likely do 100+ edits to improve posts as much as possible. Is there a limit of how many I should do in a timeframe or am I over reacting?

Comment: In theory, you can do as many edits as you like as fast as you can. In practice, you should consider that until you hit 2k rep, each of your edits must be handled by reviewers; thus you should focus your effort on questions that actively require editing to make them understandable (meaning more than changing a few lowercase `I`s or similar small grammar mistakes), and make sure the question you're editing is actually worth it and not just crap that's going to be closed anyways. E.g. [this](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5452705) seems like an edit you shouldn't have made.

Comment: Everytime a post is edited, it gets bumped. Users who watch the front page to answer questions will miss the new questions amidst your edited posts. That is bad. Also, every suggested edit requires 3-5 reviewers to approve/reject. And too many rejected edits can get you edit-banned. So brief answer - too much of anything is bad, don't overdo. Edit if you come across something that needs editing. Don't go out searching for posts to edit.

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion If the effect on the new questions queue (actually, you are referring to the *active* questions queue -- the *new* one is not so affected) is undesirable, then that should be changed.  It seems wrong to say, "Oh there's this uncorrected design flaw (apparently), so we have to remember not to _______ which otherwise would be fine".

Comment: Keep in mind that "too minor" is a valid reason to reject an edit, so if you do keep hammering away at 100/hour, you probably are going to risk a lot of rejected edits.  I reject them if they're really lazy -- you capitalize a noun, but don't bother with other obvious things -- since this just screams, "I changed something, gimme points."

Comment: @goldilocks I was referring to the front page - "recommended", "interesting" and "active" tabs. Every time a vigilante goes on an editing spree, we have to enjoy reading ancient questions.

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion Yeah me too.  I guess I shouldn't call those queues since it could be confused with the `review` stuff.  Actually there's two sets of tabs -- "active" is not in the same set as "interesting".  Split hairs ;)  There is a "newest" in one of them, that's what I bookmark.

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion: The reason why vigilantes manage to swamp those pages though is not that they edit questions/answers, not even in masses, but that they don't do good edits. Good edits need their time.

Comment: Whoops, actually bookmarking "newest" doesn't work.  That's why I always have to change tabs!  Okay then, stop editing old questions people, it's a PITA. ;D  Or maybe we could make "newest" an actual bookmarkable URL...

Comment: Yes @Deduplicator, absolutely. Just wanted to let OP know that entire community gets impacted. I didn't repeat quality because l4mpi covered that in his/her comment already. I upvoted that comment in agreement, and added some more info in my comment.

Comment: if you can do 100/hour it sounds like these are trivial edits that aren't overly beneficial. Is fixing minor grammar or capitalization really helping?

Comment: I was going to +1 this for being a good question, then changed my mind and -1 it because I don't agree one should do this. Deadlock ensured. Fortunately, the Vote Counter stands at [+1/-1], so I can escape this race condition.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Like [l4mpi](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/u/1110381) [already commented](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/267605#comment71748_267605), the number of posts you edit is not really of any concern, but the usefulness of your edits.
Quantity will mostly take care of itself if you properly cater to quality.

An edit is useful if all of these apply:

- The edited post gains value (off-topic questions, spam, NAA and the like always have less than no value!).
- Your edit was comprehensive (You improve on many/all deficits of the post).
- Your post was not radical (The content of the post remain intact).
  There are exceptions, but make sure to call it out in the edit summary:

  - You moved an integrated answer from the question into its own answer.
  - You moved info from the OPs comments into the post.

Do not edit for coding-style, [unless](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/263115) [there's](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260245) [none](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/88627) (Make it consistent, but refrain from imposing your own).
Do not edit only for grammar, unless it's really horrible. A few small i's where it should be I is ok (Correct it while you are editing it anyway).

If you follow all those points, you will probably get fewer edits done than now, but those will be *good edits*.
There's one more point: You might refrain from editing many old posts at once, because each edit bumps the questions, and we all love getting the frontpage swamped with ancient questions (admittedly a negligible issue on SO, in contrast to smaller SE-sites).

Comment: +1 But again, as per my other comment on the question, I think it is wrong to tell people not to do something (edit many old posts at once) because of a perceived flaw in the interface.  If you think the way the  "active questions" queue works needs some fine tuning, make a meta post about that.

Comment: @goldilocks: The active questions queue works in the only way that makes sense, imho. Anyway, if the edits are *good edits*, I don't think there will be any negative effect due to "natural rate-limiting" as outlined...

Comment: Okay so if I'm going to do *quality work* then I should feel free to edit as many old Q's as I want, right? ;) I don't see much point in changing the way the active queue works either.  If this actually became a "problem" -- hoards of users diligently fixing old posts -- I might even be happy to watch it happen.