# Edits which only change coding conventions (like brace placement)

Tags: discussion, edits, code-formatting

I've come across some edits that only change the coding conventions of the code in a post. Both are valid, widely-accepted conventions, both are well-formatted.

Why the edit then? And more to the point, **why are such edits accepted?** Are they following some SO recommendations that I'm not aware of?

For example, they change this:

```
public foo()
{
    ...
}
```

to this:

```
public foo() {
    ...
}
```

and sometimes they skip the spacing (oh the horror):

```
public foo(){
    ...
}
```

Most recent example I've seen: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/25222014/revisions

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/263115/when-is-it-okay-to-edit-answers-for-code-formatting?rq=1

Comment: @DavidPostill thanks! exactly my gripe. Can I mark my own post as dupe?

Comment: Try it and see :/ I flagged it as well.

Comment: Apparently I can. Aand.. done!