# Should I approve edits that are just inline code for class/method names?

Tags: discussion, review-queues

Related to, but not a duplicate of  [When is it okay to edit answers for "Code Formatting?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/263115/when-is-it-okay-to-edit-answers-for-code-formatting), which is about editing the format of code in code blocks (4-spaces markdown) rather than what behaviour we want to encourage around the (over)use of inline code (backtick markdown).

I've read a few meta posts recently to improve my reviewing and seen some contention about the questions about readability of `inline code text` for particular `class` or `method()` names especially when they're `edit`s peppered with them.

I'm letting them through material edits that are otherwise good, but skipping ones that are just these, is there guidance/consensus about edits like these?

Comment: Potentially @Cerbrus, but that question seems more about formatting in code blocks (4-spaces markdown) rather than inline code (backtick markdown).

Comment: Part of @Stij's answer `"It's OK when the readability is improved. It is not OK when the edit is essentially about stylistic preferences."` is along the thread of what sort of answers (and consensus in the reviewing community about them) that I'm hoping for.

Comment: If it puts `parts of sentences` or `product names` in code markdown that is reason for rejection.