# Should I use inline code when mentioning a class, function, interface name?

Tags: discussion, code-formatting

I always use inline code when mentioning class, interface, and function names within my English sentences. In my opinion, this makes it better to read as it separates English words and grammar from code (that does not follow the same rules).

Example:

> In order to dispose the `Foo` class, you can use the `disposeFoo` function.

Today [someone kindly told me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60031536/difference-between-imagebitmap-and-imagedata/60033582?noredirect=1#comment129842244_60033582) that:

> Name of interface are not "code". As code these are the constructors.

To me, interface names are code (and they are not plain English). And it looks to me to have [better readability](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/60033582/2).

I would like to have a clear rule about when I should (or it is allowed/encouraged to) use inline code for interface names.

Related to:

- [Should I approve edits that are just inline code for class/method names?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300822/should-i-approve-edits-that-are-just-inline-code-for-class-method-names)
- [When should code formatting be used for non-code text?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254990/when-should-code-formatting-be-used-for-non-code-text)
- [When should we use code, quotes and bold blocks?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/401459/when-should-we-use-code-quotes-and-bold-blocks)

Comment: Class names, interface names, APIs and all that _are_ code... Imho, your edit _was_ an improvement.

Comment: Is it really useful to link to the answer from here? I'm ok to abide to the community consensus, so linking this discussion there so that I'm aware of it seems fine.

Comment: And btw, why not edit the question then?

Comment: Why shouldn't the answer be linked, @Kaiido? The question is just asking what the "correct" formatting would be.

Comment: @Cerbrus My question is why should it be? OP seems to have been able to make an example general enough to not point to a particular post and avoid the "meta-effect".

Comment: I doubt you need to worry about downvotes on that answer, @Kaiido.

Comment: Apart from a minor nitpick that this is inline code and not code *blocks* per se, that "someone" who told you this is blatantly mistaken. You are definitely correct - interface names are parts of programs, and they *should* be formatted as code.

Comment: Is there a consensus to be put in rules though? I don't think so. I personally detest text which makes my brain do context switches all the time. In the example case I would find it more than enough if ImageBitmap is highlighted once the first time it comes up and then never again, because at that point I already get it. In this case I don't need it at all though because it is written in camelcase, that already implies it is code. Highlighting should help the reader, not hold their hand. But that's me.

Comment: I am afraid that's not *highlighting*, @Gimby, it's just proper formatting. No matter what personal preference one has for tag formatting, they should be formatted as tags. So do code elements (class names, interface names, function names, variable names, keywords, expressions, statements - all are the same).

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine the person who (incorrectly, imo) told him that is the author of the answer the OP edited.

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine Semantics caused by language barriers. Tag formatting okay because that is a key aspect of how content is categorised on this site, but excessive keyword *formatting* "because it is a rule" is just abuse of the setting of rules. It has to benefit the content, not one's personal preferences.

Comment: @Kaiido"And btw, why not edit the question then?" > Oops because I forgot, and I was too much focused on your awesome response that helps me a lot (and I wanted to improve a little bit the readability). Really thank you for your response it was super useful to me

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine I love python documentation. They refer to classes/functions/etc. but only when it's useful. Example [the logging howto](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html).

Comment: @Braiam except that... even the Python docs properly format class names (in the absence of interfaces as a thing) as inline code. To add to that, everything *except* for parameter names is properly formatted (the exception case is what I am on the fence about too, but they are at least formatted for emphasis otherwise.

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine and doesn't do it at every opportunity it arise, only when it makes sense, which is the point that I'm trying to make. I don't remember which, but an example of a ransom letter was one of the w3c specification where paragraphs were mostly composed of code formatting.

Comment: @Braiam I think that we may be talking about different things then. I am definitely not disagreeing that mentions should be used rather sparingly, or the content becomes a swiss cheese of references, that makes sense - but it looks more of a content problem as opposed to a formatting problem. I still maintain the stance that formatting should be done semantically: code for code, emphasis for, well, emphasis, bold for importance, quotes for cited content, etc. And it must be consistent.

Comment: *Name of interface are not "code". As code are the constructors.* When offering writing style advice, it's a good idea to use grammatical English...

Comment: @Gimby In formal writing/prose (including programming books), programming terms/code are typically formatted in a programming font for _every instance_. In the case of SO, it may seem a little more jarring because code formatting also applies a grey background, but it is no less correct. One could ostensibly format only the first instance as code and not the subsequent uses, but then they ought to include something indicating that change (e.g. "`interfaceName` (hereafter just 'interfaceName')", similar to spelling out a word/phrase and then initializing it in subsequent uses).

Comment: @Gimby (con't'd) Bear in mind that, while _you_ may find continued instances of in-line code tagging hard to parse, others may find the opposite to be true. If I were looking at an answer that switched between `interfaceName` and interfaceName, I would be wondering if the latter instances were referring to something else that would explain the change in formatting. In practically _all_ style guides, regardless of a given specific scenario, the underlying "rule zero" is to be _consistent_.

Comment: @YvesM. As an aside, I see there is one instance of adding a second space between sentences in the answer you tried to edit. If this was an intentional edit, please be aware that two spaces is wrong and has _never_ been needed for computers; it was only necessary in the era of typewriters. Further, on the internet, two spaces are condensed down to one on websites with prose like Stack Overflow (so you're doing nothing except increase the amount of storage space a given post takes up on SO's servers, however incrementally).

Comment: @cerbrus I wasn't afraid of downvotes but of the meta effect. The 4 new upvotes this answer received are from people that weren't searching for it. The meta effect (just like HNQ) "breaks" the voting system. It's best if it can be avoided.

Comment: @PM2Ring it's unfortunate the comments there were removed while being discussed here (and without the links being removed), but the actual comment I made was *"Names of interface are not "code". As code these are the constructors."* So I was saying ImageBitmap !== `ImageBitmap`. The former being the interface name, the latter being the constructor/class name.

Comment: 1/3 ... I come too late to post an answer explaining my point, I'm sorry I'll abuse the comments section. So first, note that I did follow the consensus here and reapply the edits + improve it in changing instances of `Array`, `ArrayBuffer` and `Worker` (and a missing `ImageData`). The fact that these were missing actually had some weight in my initial decision to roll back your edit. Now to my actual point, I do a distinction between an interface name, which you will find e.g in specs or in docs, and the class name/constructor.

Comment: 2/3 The former isn't necessarily accessible in user-land (e.g https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#parentnode). If we follow Tyler's rule that everything that you write in your IDE should be code and the rest text, this interface should be text (unless you write Web-IDL), but `Node` should be code, even if you were talking about the same level of interface object, not the class name. Basically, I believe that if you can put the word in a plural form, it's not code. Writing "Two `Array`s can be concatenated..." is IMM less readable than without the markup.

Comment: 3/3 In the case in question all my uses of the instance names were of that form; Admittedly in singular forms, but still they were not about the class. Had I written something like "You can use `ImageBitmap`'s `#close()` method...", then yes here the markup would have been correct since that's about the class. Once again, I heard the community consensus and will try to follow it from now-on even though I still believe this may actually confuse the readers about which level of object it's talking about.

Comment: @Kaiido Wow. I didn't realise that you were misquoted. I think you've made some good points in your comments here. Perhaps you could post an actual answer on one of the dupe targets, eg https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/369566/should-code-formatting-be-used-for-package-names

Comment: @Kaiido "*I believe if you can put the word in plural form, it's not code*" You can put any word in plural form by adding s, es, etc. That doesn't change what it's referring to, just the number of instances.

Comment: @TylerH you can't put code in plural form. I don't know all the programming languages but at least in JS since that's the language of interest in the linked answer , `ClassName` and `ClassNames` would refer to two different classes altogether.

Comment: Put the "s" outside the inline code. Singular: `ClassName` and plural: `ClassName`s

Comment: @YvesM. Which as I said is IMM less readable than without the markup. The proper solution would be to write all "`ClassName` instances", or "`ClassName` objects" but that's also verbose and I don't think that helps reading much compared to "ClassNames".

Comment: @Kaiido I don't know what IMM stands for (do you mean IMO; "in my opinion"?), but "`Classname` instances is no more correct than "`ClassName`s". It's just your opinion whether one is more readable than the other.

Comment: @TylerH all this is just about opinions, not sure what your point is... Mine was that code can't be put in plural form contrarily to what your comment stated. Doing that weird `som`e part of the wo`rd` is `i`n markup only proves that. Why the need to mark only one letter out of that word if all that is code? And "IMM" -> In My Mind but I now see it's not as common as I thought it was.

Comment: @Kaiido You're trying to argue that something is wrong, not just how you prefer. My point is that it is not wrong, it is just how you prefer. That's sort of the entire point of the question: OP is asking if you are correct when you say it is wrong.

Comment: @TylerH you are literally the only one who used the word "wrong" in that context, and neither the OP nor I did ever use the word "correct" in that thread either, except for me on the case we all agree on (when talking about the class). I am just exposing my opinion, you are the one claiming I am "wrong". I did rollback OP's edit because, in my opinion, it was not improving **my** answer. That's still something I'm allowed to do if I'm not mistaken. And they came here to have the community's opinion, a consensus.

Comment: @Kaiido I may have said the _word_ wrong, but you _argue_ that stance by saying things like "you can't do X" and "this isn't Y" etc. You're here trying to argue that marking code is wrong. As the consensus shows, it's not OP who was wrong, but you. No one's debating that authors have a right to rollback an edit they disagree with, so please don't muddy the water further by discussing things that aren't the subject of discussion, but I'll just say that even that right has limits; OPs get overridden _many_ times regarding edits they personally don't think improve a post but that actually do.

Comment: @TylerH, please read objectively the thread here. Who's pulling it in that direction? The argument we're having on this branch is about how to format words that refer to instance names when they're used in a plural form. One of my arguments is that **you can't** put code in a plural form. That's not an opinion, that's a technical fact. Your (and OP's) stance is that we should create a kind of mixed markup where only a few letters are marked as code, and others marked differently. My stance is that this highlights the fact that the whole word isn't code anymore if you can't mark it all as code.

Comment: @Kaiido both I and Yves have shown how you actually can refer to code in plural form. I guess you missed those comments?

Comment: @TylerH What do you think I was referring to with "*a kind of mixed markup where only a few letters are marked as code, and others marked differently*"? Once again this only proves that this word in plural form isn't actually code anymore since it can't technically be marked as code in it's entirety.

Answer (score 19):

> Today someone kindly told me that:
>
> > Name of interface are not "code". As code are the constructors.

That someone is wrong. Code is anything written in an IDE, which includes the names of functions, methods, interfaces, etc. Otherwise, how would you call/use them in your program?

In terms of "names that should not be marked as code", the only thing that really applies are names of languages or technologies. In other words, don't write `C#` or `Visual Studio` or even `Windows Server 2008 R2`... those things aren't code.

But keep on keepin' on<sup>[1](https://www.google.com/search?q=keep+on+keepin+on+meaning)</sup> with your lovely `camelCaseInterfaceName` tagging, because that's correct.

Comment: This is all 100% true. The only caveat/condition that I would add is... if you're formatting every couple of words in your post with inline code formatting, that's almost certainly going to have a negative impact on readability, so you might consider not doing it. Not because it's semantically wrong, but because overuse of formatting makes a post difficult to read.

Comment: Thanks for making my point: " Code is anything you write in your IDE, " Unless you're a specs or docs editor you don't write the interface name in you IDE, only the class names or constructors. Take for instace in JS/DOM the *ParentNode* interface. That interface isn't exposed but it exists under the hood. So you won't ever write it in your IDE and thus by your definition if an answer had to talk about it we should be writing "*The ParentNode interface is used for all `Nodes` that have children.*".

Comment: @Kaiido My answer was not exhaustive except perhaps in what you should _not_ write. Given that an Interface is code that you can call by using custom code, that... still makes it code. The fact that MDN and the WHATWG show it in code formatting just further underscores that it's code. I've edited the answer slightly to reduce the possibility of interpreting it as person- or context-specific.

Comment: In WHATWG it's either "An `InterfaceName` object ...", or they do define expressions like "An interface name is an instance of an `InterfaceName`.".  As for MDN I'm not sure the consistency is that great there, but if we take [this sentence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentElement) as an example: "*An `Element` that is the parent element of the current node, or `null` if there isn't one.*" you can see that they use the code markup for the class, not for "*element*"  nor "*node*".

Comment: @Kaiido Yes, now you're making _my_ point; formal names that refer to an instance of a declared code entity are given code highlighting; no one here is suggesting you should be highlighting the English word "interface" as code.

Comment: But a "node" in this context is not just a "node" from the Merriam Webster, it's obviously to us an instance of `Node`, yet they write "a node", not "a `Node`".

Comment: No, a node is an endpoint of something and is perfectly fine English. The time you highlight it as code is when you have something named `Node` that you are referring to. I don't really see a point in trying to find endless hairs to try and split here; code is code; highlight code as code.

Comment: A "node" here is not literraly the vertex, no. They use the DOM jargon "node" to mean "an instance of `Node`" as defined by the [DOM specs](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-node). MDN does assume that its readers are aware of such jargon, just like "element" is not either any of the definitions on the MW, but once again jargon to mean "an instance of `Element`". My point is that in my use these words weren't code. That's the whole issue, not hair splitting. But I can see you won't have the arguments to make me change my opinion, so this discussion can end now.

Answer (score -19):

> I always use code block when mentioning class, interface, function names within my english sentences.

That's the issue. You shouldn't *always* use it; **only use it when it makes sense semantically**. Remember, formatting is to make text more *readable* and that you can *highlight important context*. We don't need post that looks like ransom letters. There are not hard and fast rules; use your best judgement. If you think you are using too much formatting, you are probably doing too much. At the end, it is all a matter of preferences.

Comment: I do not agree with your "That's the issue" statement. Using `code blocks`, even when there are a lot of them, helps reading large amount of text, and helps distinguish english words from code-related stuff.

Comment: This. But I'm afraid we are going to be in a minority. Are you by any chance also that one person in the company that manages to produce readable documentation?

Comment: @0stone0 "when mentioning class [...] within my english sentences". They aren't blocks, they are inline. You do not need <pre><code>blocks<code><pre> if you are writing a sentence.

Comment: @Gimby if by readable documentation you mean actual documentation, I don't know. I just know that I haven't found documentation that is useful and non-ambiguous.

Comment: @Braiam Who said you have to use `<pre>` or `<code>`? The OP just used the wrong terminology when referring to _inline code_. So, all you need to use within your English sentence is \`ClassName\` (i.e., two backticks surrounding the inline code).

Comment: @41686d6564standsw.Palestine still my general recommendation applies: do not make ransom letters.

Comment: @Braiam what you call a "ransom letter" I, as most others, call "properly formatted post". This is not an argument, it's a logical fallacy.

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine again, I'm not saying that you shouldn't, I'm saying that do it with moderation, aka: not a freaking ransom letter with a bunch of keywords.

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine I believe his point is that using inline code can draw undo attention to code names and reducing the formatting can actually improve readability in some places.  Not sure I agree with it, but it doesn't seem to be a logical fallacy to me.

Comment: I think this post could be improved by providing an example of something that looks better (to the author of this post) without one or more of the code names being marked as inline code. The point is not to continue an argument over what looks good, but to provide an illustration of the author's opinion.

Comment: @JosiahYoder eh, to clarify why I referred to it as a logical fallacy - calling something a ransom letter does not provide an argument for playing fast and loose with formatting rules. It's a kind of begging the question fallacy unless illustrated, which is exactly the point you elegantly made above.

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine it `does` when `it` looks like `this`. There are time and place for inline code syntax, "always" isn't it.

Comment: @Braiam again, if `does`, `it`, and `this` are all code, then I see nothing but a properly formatted sentence. This is the reason why I said it demonstrates nothing. Your example uses *arbitrarily* formatted words as code to illustrate why what is *semantically* code should not be formatted as such.

Comment: @Braiam Yes, inline code is a formatting tool. However, it's not (at least shouldn't be) used to _highlight_ words like **bold** and _italic_, for example. Instead, it's used to separate code from the rest of the text. Yes, sometimes it's pretty easy to infer that a given word is code without formatting it as such, but that doesn't mean we should write it as plain text. That's like saying we shouldn't _always_ surround quotes with double quotations if it's obvious that this part of the text is a quote.