# What to do about an edit by someone with edit permissions who added no value to an edit

Tags: discussion, edits, revision-history

See edit 6 here: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/416327/revisions

As you can see, they've done nothing to improve the question and have simply just moved things around. What's the best course of action here? Edit said person's edit further, or just hit the rollback button on edit 5. Also what can we do to educate people like this who have this capability and use it incorrectly?

Comment: If you want to rollback, then it should be to revision 3. Revision 4 just adds `{}`, which is unnecessary and revision 5 should have been a new answer instead of an edit.

Comment: Ping them in  a comment, rollback their edit, check their profile and if there is a clear pattern use a custom moderator flag and explain what is going on and why it needs to stop. Ultimately post on meta.

Comment: @BDL While I tend to agree with you, edit 5 was an approved one.

Comment: @JamieBarker: By some reviewers: yes, not by the author. In general, this edit should have never been approved. But since the edit is from 2014, I agree with you that it doesn't make sense to role it back now.

Comment: @JamieBarker Sadly, you missed the point in my edit. I think you are unaware of Yoda Conditions (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions/). That's what I did! I am not sure how you see there was no value in it.

Comment: @AhmadAwais because that is a coding style which is entirely personal preference. Which, adds no value. You should edit code to make the formatting easier to read if the indentation or line breaks are messed up, changing it for **just** this reason is pointless

Comment: @AhmadAwais From the wiki article itself: "_Placing the constant value in the expression does not change the behavior of the program_"

Comment: @JamieBarker @George That's not all I did. I also changed the console message and the weird `something` variable name with `prop`. That's adding value in my book and it makes for more readable and understandable code.

Comment: @AhmadAwais the _weird_ variable names are okay in this context as it's an example. _"Critics of Yoda conditions see the lack of readability as a disadvantage"_ (taken from the wiki you linked yourself) a lot more people use the **standard** way of doing this kind of logic as it's a lot more readable, so don't use the reason that you were making the code more _readable_.

Comment: I am not using the reason to justify anything I just find the atittude here completely hostile! I did try to add value even if both of you fail to see that. It was not a spam attempt to add links and runaway with it. I did add value. You can call it subjective or what not but this hostility is uncalled for. I wish it was handled better.

Comment: @AhmadAwais there is no hostility, we're or I'm just trying to point out why it was a _bad_ (superfluous) edit, which you don't seem to understand. Please read [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/263121/2315360) in which you can see it's more than just 2 people agree that these kinds of edits shouldn't happen.

Comment: That's much well written as compared to the discussion here. Thanks.

Comment: Are we really rolling back a 4 months old edit?

Comment: @AhmadAwais No one is being hostile, they're simply explaining why the edit is problematic.  That you were *trying* to be helpful, even though you were actually being harmful, is the reason that all that happened was a rollback of the edit and a comment.  If people thought you were being malicious there'd be much more serious consequences.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The edit wasn't just superfluous, it was actively wrong.  It's inappropriate to go around changing posts to alter their style and semantic preferences to fit your own, as was done here.  Since this edit wasn't just useless, but *improper*, you should roll it back (as has since been done).  If you want to comment, you can.  If the user re-applies the edit, or you notice that edits like this are a pattern for that user, then flag for moderator attention and explain the situation (and stop interacting with them from then on; let the moderator do their job).

If the edit was actually just superfluous, and not harmful, then you wouldn't want to roll it back (rolling back an edit that doesn't make any meaningful change is just as bad as the meaningless edit was) and it's generally not worth acting on at all in an isolated case.  If you notice a pattern of a user making *lots* of edits that don't make meaningful changes, to the point that it actually starts inhibiting use of the active question feed, for example, then that's time to flag for a mod and explain the situation.  But again, that's not the situation for this particular edit.