# When reviewing, is it OK to accept code edits to an answer?

Tags: support, review-queues, suggested-edits, code

While doing reviews for suggested edits something like this occurs frequently
[image]
with comment like

> ... removed unused try-catch block ...

I strongly feel that if an answer "needs" code editing as much as this example did (in someones opinion) a new answer should be created instead of changing the code, even the changes would not change the functionality itself.

Comment: Edit in example was just rejected by reason **This edit was intended to address the author of the post and makes no sense as an edit. It should have been written as a comment or an answer.**

Comment: Related: [When is it okay to edit answers for "Code Formatting"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/263115/when-is-it-okay-to-edit-answers-for-code-formatting)

Comment: Side note: That's a bad answer. You're supposed to reuse the same `Random` over and over, not create a new one each call, catching all exception types is ill advised unless you're writing the global, stop gap handling, and catching  `Throwable` is even worse. Downvote to oblivion.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

No, this is not acceptable. This changes the OP's intent; if someone thinks different code is appropriate, they should post their own answer, or they should comment under the answer suggesting that part of the code (in this case the try-catch) is unused/superfluous and therefore should be removed, allowing the OP to make the final determination on whether to remove it.

Answer (score -1):

No, this is unacceptable in general. It should be rejected as **clearly conflicts with author's intent**. If anyone has an idea to improve the code, they should leave a comment and let the author decide whether to accept the proposal. Usually codes are written as-is for some reasons by the author that may or may not be clear.

Personally, I reject all code edit if it changes how the code works, even if it's obvious. For example, this code edit could be rejected:

```
i += 1;
i++;
```

Sometimes there's obvious typo in code that can be safely approved if it's fixed in an edit suggestion.

```
int input;
read(inpt);
if (iput == 0)

int input;
read(input);
if (input == 0)
```

Be careful when handling these as an edit may not be actually fixing a typo:

```
if (A == B)
if (A === B)
```

In JavaScript or PHP that totally changed how the code works. Reject the edit or if the edit is otherwise good, remove the code change using **Improve edit**.