# How to review suggested edits that fix security issues?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, suggested-edits

In the last days, I encountered several suggested edits that try to fix code in answers that are prone to SQL injections, similar to this edit:

[image]

The question is now: Which action should be taken in the review queue? This [meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361871/when-reviewing-is-it-ok-to-accept-code-edits-to-an-answer) suggests that changes to code which modify already working code are not ok. The [FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260245/when-should-i-make-edits-to-code) doesn't cover cases where already correct and working code gets improved/modified. I also don't think that [How to deal with dangerous answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276496/how-to-deal-with-dangerous-answers?answertab=votes#tab-top) answers the question because the current code is not actively or intentional harmful but just has security implications.

At the moment, I'm tempted to reject such edits because they drastically change the code. But I do see value in these edits because we all know that code is often enough copied from SO without deeply understanding it.

Comment: Woof, that's one dedicated warrior.  He's not going to keep that up for long, a couple of rejects are going to discourage him.  No reason to reject if the code is okay or the question isn't about injection or it is older than a month.  Do ping this editor, post a link to this question as a comment on one of his posts.

Comment: @HansPassant: Ping is done. For the rest: It's might be hard to say if the code is okay. You'd have to check back with the question and have the relevant domain knowledge and hope that you don't break anything that was implicitly required by op.

Comment: Think about what you just said, reviewers don't know what code that doesn't suffer from SQL injection looks like.  What the heck does it take to get them to click Skip?

Comment: I think the general principle of edit still apply: editor should not change other's code. Security flaw is not special. Every question focuses on a specific problem, if the question is not particularly asking security issue, no need for distraction. Moreover, if someone blindly copy-paste code, it's their fault.

Comment: I have encountered these as well, all from the same user. Because I'm not too familiar with SQL, I have decided to skip them, but I'm sure they have their best intention and that the code should be valid. Just, not up to me to decide.

Comment: The only objection I have is that the suggested edit is unnecessarily verbose. If I actively reviewed these I might even consider reject and improve. :-) `cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text` should do. In general, you would have to carefully review such edits to ensure they don't inadvertently muck things up, because there's also things like `NULL`s and parameter length to consider. Even so, imperfect code that uses parameters in a way that a reader could easily fix should still be preferable to having a copy-pasteable answer that falls to injection.

Comment: @liliscent - "Moreover, if someone blindly copy-paste code, it's their fault" -- eeshk, while you're right that it's their fault, and I get the principle of it being irrelevant to the question, it's all of us who suffer if code ends up in a production system somewhere with an SQLi vulnerability. Don't forget there's every chance that the hypothetical person blindly copy-pasting turns out to be developing software for your bank!

Comment: How do I downvote a comment? (The first comment to the question)

Comment: @SargeBorsch You oppose a sensible response to it. What's wrong with that comment?

Answer (score 42):

An edit that fixes a potential security flaw in an answer, is a good edit.

Injection is one of the top vulnerabilities in the [OWASP Top 10](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Top_Ten_Project), and everything we can do to prevent it, makes the world safer for end users. That includes setting a good example here on Stack Overflow.

Stack Overflow is one of the first sites that people encounter when googling their programming problem, let's make sure they encounter answers that follow proper security practice.

Just make sure that the fix doesn't somehow invalidate the answer, and doesn't introduce new errors. If you aren't sure, <kbd>Skip</kbd>.

Comment: I'd add that if you're not sure the edit won't break anything, but you can see it intended to fix an SQL injection issue, it would be kind to leave a comment on the answer to that effect and give the author the chance to fix the code themselves (and not do it again in future answers). We have a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/601300/4137916) that is often linked to as a way of explaining what it is, and the search it links to gives some questions on how to do proper parameterization. (Though not .NET, alas -- [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4624866/4137916) is nice for that.)

Comment: Some answerers don't like their answers being significantly edited. Leaving a comment for OP to fix themselves should be better.

Comment: @user202729 If they don't like it, they should write better answers. Communal editing is one of the core features of SO and I am very glad it is.

Comment: @HermannDöppes That doesn't contradict my comment. Yes, either way should be fine.

Comment: @user202729 "If you are not comfortable with the idea of your contributions being collaboratively edited by other trusted users, **this may not be the site for you.**"

Comment: @Braiam "**significantly edited**". Fix grammar and formatting etc. should be fine.

Comment: @user202729 even a monkey can do that kind of edits. Why would you require "trusted users", **trusted**, to do such lowly edits?

Comment: @Braiam I understand "trusted" there as "trusted that they know the [edit rules](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260245) and behave accordingly", not "trusted that they have the domain-specific knowledges to write an answer". In any case, editing an answer to add  or change the method used is never ok (except community wiki of course).

Comment: @user202729 "If you see something that needs improvement, click edit!" The edit rules never rule out any kind of edit, so long as it is an improvement. Formatting fixing is an improvement, so it's fixing a vulnerability.

Comment: @Braiam I think you mean... "so _is_ fixing a vulnerability"? (Emphasis mine.) Unfortunately I can't edit your comment ;-)

Comment: Yeah, that happens when you edit your comment several times and end up deleting everything and starting again.

Answer (score 21):

I think **a *lot* of code from SO answers gets copied/pasted** by people who don't take the time to fully understand how/why it works.  **That's fine, but it means we need to hold copy-pasteable code to a high standard.**

**Code with security holes is *not* ok.  It doesn't count as "already working" in my book**, unless comments inside the code block itself point this out, and/or list some special circumstances where the code is usable.

A sentence in the text outside is *not* sufficient; people skim SO answers looking for what they want.  That's not a bad thing; maybe they already know some of what the answer explains and were just looking for a nice implementation of something, or maybe they'll get around to grokking it later.  SO answers should support skimming by bolding a key/topic sentence here and there, and/or using `---` dividers and headings.

**Code that "happens to work" for some inputs but fails for others is not "working code".**

If you find problems, especially in a highly-upvoted answer on a popular question, fix it with an edit if you know the language / subject well enough that you're confident it's a real problem and you know how to fix it.  That's one of the major reasons why users are allowed to edit answers from other users.

If the user who posted the answer doesn't like your edit, they can make their own edit (starting from the revision before your edit if they want).  But until they get around to it, it's much better to have a fixed answer than a buried comment about a serious problem.  Most people welcome improvements to their answers, when the editor and editee agree that an edit was an improvement.

---

#### Reviewing such edits

Do *not* reject it just because you don't understand it.  **Only reject if you *know* the language / tag and know it's a bad code change.**  If you don't know the subject, skip it, because it definitely requires domain knowledge (unlike a grammar or formatting cleanup).

**Approve if it fixes bugs, including but not limited to security bugs.**  If it fixes bugs but introduces new ones, or unnecessarily makes the code significantly worse in some way, reject (with a custom message about *what* the problem is) or improve it.

---

P.S.

It's too bad there isn't a mechanism to preferentially show code-change reviews and tag-wiki edits to reviewers with score / badges in question tags, so reviewers could spend more of their time looking at changes that only they are qualified to handle.

(This is why I pretty much never do reviews.  I'm an expert in less-popular tags (assembly), and watching activity in those tags directly is much more useful to the overall quality of SO than spending time mostly Skipping reviews of posts in popular languages I know very little about, only being able to do anything useful on ones that anyone could have handled.)

Comment: On that PS: if you don't watch your tag like a hawk, you could use a filter on the review queue to only review the questions that carry that tag. That way, you can review within your expertise, and keep these questions away from the general public, that likely knows less about the subject.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth: You can?  I didn't know that.  I might give that a try sometime when I don't feel like working on any of the dozen tabs of half-finished answers I have open. :P

Comment: You can even create [links](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=assembly) to a specific filtered queue. Triage doesn't support it, but I believe all the others do.

Comment: `It doesn't count as "already working" in my book [...]` yes this.