# Was it correct to edit out this question's PHP issue?

Tags: discussion, questions

This edit is old: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8631577.

But I do not know enough about PHP to determine if this correction to the question was welcomed or not. To me, it seems that the edit may have solve the problem that was asked, and as such has invalidated the question.

**Can someone knowledgeable about PHP double-check if it should be rolled back or not?**

Comment: You really don't need PHP knowledge for this, such edits should always be rolled back.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Having a typo in `upload_max_filesize` could definitely be the source of the issue. PHP does not raise any warning if an extra parameter is added to `php.ini`, and it has defaults for all (most?) settings, so that would be easy to miss.

I'm not sure how to handle it the best according to Stack Overflow guidelines. I guess reverting the edit, and posting an answer pointing out the typo would do.

Comment: Typos are non on-Topic on SO, the question is closed accordingly now.

Comment: i am knowledgeable about PHP. this is the correct answer.

Comment: Polygnome, closing the question is good, but pointing out the typo would be best for users consulting the thread, if that ever happen. I will post a comment over there.

Comment: @romaricdrigon nicely done.

Comment: @romaricdrigon, you're absolutely right. Also closing this is probably one reason why new users specifically think SO is unfriendly. On that note we've all had times where one little misspelling screws us over. having a reference for those occasions is pretty handy, and IMO what makes SO so valuable as a resource.

Comment: @Polygnome for completeness' sake: it _is_ on topic! Most of our questions are about debugging, and debugging includes spotting that one silly typo. It's just that these questions are unlikely to help future readers; just read the close banner! If there's a typo that _is_ useful for future readers, there's no need to close it in my opinion.

Comment: @AndrasDeak 99% of the typos that land here of off-topic (so in general, my statement holds). The close reason pretty much covers it.

Comment: @Polygnome The word you're looking for is *off-topic*.

Answer (score 18):

*Maybe.* It's unclear whether that was the issue or just a bad copy and paste. It certainly was bad to correct such a technical detail which *may* have been the issue, so I have rolled it back to the original.

Comment: Those users accepting this edit should be review banned. This is editing 101: never ever change code in questions!

Comment: @PatrickHofman We shouldn't review-ban for very old reviews. But a warning or reminder may do.

Comment: @PatrickHofman "never ever" is too strong.  I frequently change code to fix indentation (except in Python) and to shorten long lines.  The Python issue means that you can't just say "never ever change non-whitespace in code".  You are left with "never ever make non-cosmetic changes in code" - but "fixing a typo" can sometimes be a cosmetic change, and sometimes significant.  Reviewers need to "skip" if they are not sure.

Comment: It's, like, you're encountering a phrase in Chinese and you think it's smart to run a spell-check on it – even tho' you don't read Chinese.

Comment: @usr2564301 when people's code is comparable to chinese for a foreigner, it's safe to assume OP doesn't understand their code either.

Comment: @MartinBonner I would agree with you if this was an answer, but changing *question* code has the possibility of fixing the issue. Answers are more likely to have innocent typos that can be fixed no problem (if your reviewers accept it...)

Comment: @Clint Adding line wrap and indentation in C++ code will never fix the issuer.  Also, I don't have to worry about my reviewers accepting the change...

Comment: @MartinBonner Right, I wasn't trying to suggest that formatting edits are bad on questions. I wasn't clear but I was focusing on the fixing typos bit.

Comment: @MartinBonner [You shouldn't be changing someone else's cosmetic formatting either](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/263115/500202)