# Why were these edits rejected as "completely superfluous or actively harm readability"?

Tags: discussion, rejected-edits, editing-help, reject-reasons

I am wondering about these three edits, which were rejected for the same reason:

- [24698499](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/24698499)
- [24765018](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/24765018)
- [24764959](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/24764959)

> This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read, easier to find, more accurate or more accessible. Changes are either completely superfluous or actively harm readability.

In each case, I was doing things like fixing minor grammar/capitalization/punctuation errors, adding backticks around inline code, or decreasing excessive leading indentation in code blocks (which increases readability on smaller screens by showing more text without scrolling side-to-side).

According to the "How to Edit" guidelines:

> - fix grammatical or spelling errors
> - clarify meaning without changing it
> - correct minor mistakes

Why do these edits not adhere to these guidelines, and why do they "not make the post even a little bit easier to read ... or more accessible", or "actively harm readability"?

Comment: Related: [When is it okay to edit answers for “Code Formatting?”](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/263115/7795130)

Comment: The first one looks fine for me, but the other two are not good enough. They fix some stuff, but also add bad and superfluous stuff. Formatting a single letter as code, even when it is a class name, is not useful and changing the placement of the braces is superfluous (or even harmful when I argue that you think your placement style is better than OPs style, although it isn't). I would have approved the first, but "reject and edit"ed the other two.

Comment: In the first edit, I would have improved because you added both a colon and a semicolon to the end of a sentence. No reason to do that. I would suggest not adding formatting if the author didn't use it, with the exception of code (for runs of code that are obviously code, not just individual words), blockquote, bullets, & numbers. In one of your edits you bolded "is-a", and I don't see how that helps the question.

Comment: In the first edit, you seemed to have changed the correct `till` into the incorrect `til`. In the second and third edits, you actively changed the code style for no apparent reason.

Comment: While till is correct, 'til as a contraction for until is colloquial/informal but not actually *wrong* per all schools of thought. However replacing valid proper english with colloquialisms is not proper.

Comment: I would've probably changed it to "to" instead. It has always annoyed me that "till" is correct as a contraction for "until". Why do you _add_ a letter when the whole purpose of a contraction is to remove them? (Sorry I'm not really addressing the main point of the question at all.)

Comment: @Don'tPanic Strangely enough, it's apparently the other way around: "till" (or "til" at that point in Middle English) is the base word, with "until" being an extended form similar to "unto". In any case, certainly agreed that we shouldn't be changing modern English spellings to Middle English ones.

Comment: @manveti interesting! TIL ;-)

Comment: You propose a lot of edits, I see dozens of them in the last couple of weeks that got accepted.  Hard to see which did not, presumably you listed them in this meta question.  Review is far too subjective to assume it can be 100% correct at all times.

Comment: Correct @HansPassant, I listed the ones I had questions about in the question. I did not know about til/till, learned something new.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First off, thank you for asking. One of the best ways to get help if you're still unclear after reading the FAQs and other documentation is to ask here on Meta. (Ignore the downvotes.)

---

**First edit:** https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/24698499

- Good:

  - Fixed excessive indentation of code block
  - Improper capitalization of 'Underline' and 'Italics' fixed
- Bad:

  - "Till" was grammatically correct; replaced with "til" which is informal/colloquial/many consider incorrect
  - Appended `:;` at the end of a sentence; this was probably intended to just be `:` but was typo'd

No other potential issues with the text.

This is the most "borderline" of these suggested edits that I can see. Overall the code indentation fix did make the post significantly more readable, but the replacement of the valid English word "till" with the less-appropriate "til" was not. (I'm considering the `:;` appended to the sentence as an honest typo instead of an intentional change.)

I personally would have selected 'reject and edit' to roll back the till/til change and fix the typo.

**Second edit:** https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/24765018

As mentioned in the comments, changing the code style of someone's post is a big no-no, especially if the change is simply to your preference. Recommended reading is this post: [When is it okay to edit answers for "Code Formatting?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/263115/when-is-it-okay-to-edit-answers-for-code-formatting)

- Good:

  - Fixed some slightly awkward phrasing for clarity (*"This will just make the default constructor not being called."* became: *"This will just prevent the default constructor from being called."*)
- Bad:

  - Changed the original code style
  - Unclear edit summary: "Formatting, backticks, etc".

As mentioned, changing the code style is pretty egregious; I would have rejected due to that as well because it didn't make the post any more readable than previously. The edit summary also doesn't reflect your changes; keeping in mind the character limit, I would have said something like "Improved code formatting and reworded sentence to make it clearer."

(The grammatical fix for the mentioned sentence did make the point much clearer, in my opinion, though; I think it's important to point out that *this* sort of edit is quite helpful.)

Some people will argue that the highlighting of the class names throughout the answer using code formatting makes it less readable. I personally prefer that the class names be highlighted consistently throughout the answer so I could track them easily; not everyone agrees with this point of course.

**Third edit:** https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/24764959

- Good:

  - Fixed improper code formatting using `<pre>` and `<code>` HTML sections.
  - Fixed all of the improper grammar present in the post: improper capitalization, missing punctuation, etc.
- Bad:

  - Changed the original code style

If you had left the code as written instead of changing the positions of the opening braces, and just replaced the improper HTML tags with proper code blocks (three backticks or four spaces), I would have accepted this edit. However changing the code format for no reason as far as I can tell didn't help the answer's readability at all, and should be avoided.

---

As an addendum, people are extremely sensitive to editors changing the code of other peoples' answers or questions. Basic things like fixing excessive whitespace (eg the whole block is indented 16 spaces for some reason) is fine; but when you actually start changing the *contents* of the code block itself is when you need to be extra careful and have a very good reason to do so. Some reviewers might have found updating the brace placement to match the C# code standards to be acceptable; your reviewers (and others, myself included) do not.

There are numerous questions here on Meta regarding edits to code, whether they were appropriate, what to do in various situations, etc.

Here are some resources about editing code in other peoples' questions. The first is the post which was linked in the comments on your question, and which I linked to previously. The other two were migrated to Meta Stack Exchange when that site was split from Stack Overflow, so are a little harder to find if you just search Meta SO.

- [When is it okay to edit answers for "Code Formatting?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/263115/when-is-it-okay-to-edit-answers-for-code-formatting)
- [When is it appropriate to edit someone else's code?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101583/when-is-it-appropriate-to-edit-someone-elses-code)
- [How far can I refactor the code in someone else's question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88627/how-far-can-i-refactor-the-code-in-someone-elses-question)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer and linking to other questions!