# Why was my edit that fixed code indentation rejected for actively harming the readability of the post?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, rejected-edits, specific-edit

I made an edit in this post.
[Excel VBA Web Scraping IE NAVIGATE method Works Vs MSXML2.XMLHTTP60 not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61327329/excel-vba-web-scraping-ie-navigate-method-works-vs-msxml2-xmlhttp60-not-working) 
Edit rejected with this reason:
This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read, easier to find, more accurate or more accessible. Changes are either completely superfluous or actively harm readability.
The code provided by op looks like this:
[image]
I suggested an indenting of the VBA procedure, so it had to look like this:
[image]
Just curious, in which way this **actively harms readability** and **does not make the post even a little bit easier to read**?

Comment: Just a nitpick from me but the full sentence is "Changes are *either* completely superfluous *or* actively harm readability". The message that the reject-reason is, a bit clumsily, trying to get across is that it's appreciated to not do minor edits like that because it all has to go through a review untill you reach 2k reputation.

Comment: @ivarni I am not an editing hunter. Since I am a member of stackoverflow, more than two years probably, I did less than 10 edits, and I don't do edits for my reputation. I did it only because I wanted it to be more readable for me, while I posted a response there.

Comment: I'm not sure what triggered the need to tell me you're not an "editing hunter" whatever that is. I'm just pointing out what the message means.

Comment: @ivarni Ok, even supposing the edit is so minor. Why it had to be rejected? It visually improves the readability. What is the harm causing it to reject?

Comment: _"Changes are either completely superfluous ___or___ actively harm readability"_ If it's not harmful, it must've been [superfluous](https://www.lexico.com/synonym/superfluous).

Comment: @ErikA it was not the case of an editing war

Comment: @armagedescu maybe not, but the answer is still relevant: "You should not be making edits that make changes that are a matter of personal preference; the changes should be clearly and objectively better. In terms of code, you shouldn't be changing code from one perfectly acceptable style of formatting to another, based on your personal preferences."

Answer (score 13):

You were far from complete in that [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/26048983).

First of all VBA doesn't go in a stacksnippet, that is only for HTML/CSS/JavaScript code blocks that are expected to be runable. You really should refrain changing code as much as possible unless it is a big mess. Fixing only indentation is not a high prio edit. See also [When is it okay to edit answers for "Code Formatting?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/263115/when-is-it-okay-to-edit-answers-for-code-formatting)

If you edit a post, you need to fix everything. Your goal should be to make that post perfect so no editor after you feels the urge to edit that post again.

In the specific edit you missed:

- Linking the site instead of leaving the bare URL
- After a point and a comma there should be a space
- In English it still is common to use a capital I when we refer to our self.
- Sentences end with a .
- The whole text is run on of words. Edit in proper sentences, maybe a line break or paragraph
- Remove code snippets for code that is not runable.

Indenting is a code style. While I would prefer to indent the body of a function or sub, there are devs that refrain from doing that. If indenting is the only thing to fix, I would move on to the next post, specially if my edit goes in the review queue to be seen by at least three people.

When you make all needed edits make sure to summarize clearly in your edit comment what changes you made and why. Replace a stack snippet with a plain code block looks rather invasive for reviewers, your comment should point the reviewers on the issues you fixed.

Comment: There was no need to link the URL because it was a parameter passed to some function. No one care about the site, it is just a string to be passed to VBA. I clearly summarised in comment the meaning of my change. If some edit is far from being complete, anyone can improve the edit, because this is a community.

Comment: The edit is rejected, it won't get un-rejected no matter how much you argue about it. It is up to you how you handle that great loss. For sure it is not by arguing with me.

Comment: That is not my reasoning. As I already said, I am not an edit hunter. Do I have to be afraid to ask a question or to make an edit?

Comment: *" it won't get un-rejected no matter how much you argue about it"* Not anymore, it can't. Wai Ha Lee already submitted another edit. :-)

Comment: @armagedescu You can ask questions, but if you don't like the answer that's not really our problem. You asked why it was rejected and several people told you why it was rejected. As rene is saying; how you use that information is up to you.

Comment: @armagedescu you need to be conscientious. If that makes you afraid then I can't help you with that, I'm sorry.

Comment: @CodyGray I wasn't thrilled by that edit. Expect a meta post about that edit in 6 to 8 ...

Comment: @rene I am asking because recently there was a survey of how friendly is the community to members who asks, responses and makes edits. Not because I am afraid of voting wars, or so. I never involve in that things.

Comment: Let's not blow things out of proportion here. Having one of your edits rejected is not a sign of unfriendliness. It just means that two people disagreed that your edit was a substantive improvement to the post. Presumably, your motivation for asking this question was to understand how you can improve your editing skills and make better edits in the future. Rene has given you *great* advice for that, which can be summed up by "fix *all* the problems in the post". @arm

Comment: @CodyGray ok. Thanks for edit by the way.